# When should you convert continuous variable to categorical for chi-squared test?

Tags: regression, anova, chi-squared-test

I am doing some analysis on a large data set `n = 34000` and I am looking to compare one continuous variable across 5 different groups. While I can preform an ANOVA test on this data, and see significant results, I am not sure this is the right way of approaching this problem.

Since `n` is so large, any difference in variation is going to show significant results (very low p-values). I am thinking I could bin the continuous variable and perform a chi-square test to get a more meaningful result.

Any comments on the above would be appreciated.

Comment: How would doing that make it more meaningful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I miss the logic of this. Since you are almost certain to find significant diferences, you want to use a less adequate method which doesn't fully account for the nature of the data (continuous instead of discrete)?

I think you should rather re-think your problem and decide if the (statistically) significant differences you find with ANOVA are (practically) significant. One resource which has made me realize the difference between both "significances" is the book [Sense and nonsense of statitical inference, by C. Wang](https://www.amazon.es/Sense-Nonsense-Statistical-Inference-Controversy/dp/0824787986) which I recommend.